# Error of reading character from string

Tags: c++, windows, shared-memory

I defined a structure like this

```
typedef struct movieinfo {
    string name;
    double grade;     //
    int duration;     //
    string type;      //
    int starttime[10];
    int time;         //
    int place[10];    //
    int price;        //
    int ttlTickets[10]; //
    int rmnTickets[10]; //
}movieInfo[10];
```

and when I initialize the first two movieinfo, it works properly. The problem occurs when I try to assign the third movieinfo just the same way as the first two.

And it say that an unhandled exception occurs at 0x....., an access conflict occurs when reading at 0x..... (I translated it from my mother language, please ignore the inaccuracy.)

The problem didn't exist before I changed the member of the structure. I wonder if it is the size of the structure that caused the exception.

PS: I'm using the structure as shared memory like this:

```
HANDLE hMap = CreateFileMapping(
    INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,
    NULL,
    PAGE_READWRITE,
    0,
    sizeof(movieInfo),
    "movie");

LPVOID pData = MapViewOfFile(
    hMap,
    FILE_MAP_WRITE,
    0,
    0,
    sizeof(movieInfo));

if (pData != NULL) {
    ZeroMemory(pData, sizeof(movieInfo));
}

movieInfo *mi = reinterpret_cast<movieInfo*>(pData);
```

Comment: `movieInfo` is an array of 10 `movieinfo` .  `mi` is a pointer to an array of 10 `movieinfo`s.  (Not a pointer to the first struct of an array of 10). I guess you might be doing something like `mi[1]` in your code, which will then access out of bounds of the mapped space (trying to access a second lot of 10 structs).  If you use `movieinfo` instead of `movieInfo` in the last line, it might work.

Comment: I would recommend (a) use better variable names, (b) don't use array typedefs, (c) post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). At the moment you are asking us to speculate about what mistakes you might be making in the rest of your code that you didn't bother to post.

Comment: @M.M Thanks a lot for your helpful advice! This is the last time that I use array typedef.

Answer (score 0):

The 0x... error is due to trying to access a variable from a memory location not within your program. Something is wrong with how you initialize your arrays or how you zero your structs (due to something wrong in mapViewOfFile())

Comment: Yeah! Mainly because I didn't use the typedef properly.